# JavaScript will alert nodeValue, but when trying to display the text, it's null or causes errors

Tags: javascript

I have been having tremendous trouble getting this to work. There is no reason (to my knowledge) that this shouldn't work.

```
var xpath = '/course/module[@id=\''+modId+'\']/child::*';
var getData = sxe(xmldoc, xpath);
var result = getData.iterateNext();
```

The function returns the xpath. Just looks cleaner. This works 100%.

```
while (results)
{
    var text = result.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].nodeValue;
    document.write(text); // returns null
}
```

For the example, I use document.write, it returns null, but in my actual script, it usually says `childNodes` or whatever method I'm trying to access the data (I thought this would help) it never returns it. It causes an error and breaks it. When I use `alert()`, I get the exact text I want, everything works perfectly!

What is happening?!

Comment: You do know that `document.write()` as well as `innerHTML` doesn't work with X(HT)ML documents, right? Just in case you're using one of those.

Comment: I was not aware of that, but I avoid innerHTML ... which is why I have so much difficulty. I was using document.write to keep my example short. In the actual script, the text is appended to a <a> tag and that is appended, and that is, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Some of my XML data was missing a title attribute. This caused an error when trying to pass it to a variable, but alerting something that doesn't exist just ... doesn't alert it. So, it makes sense to why it works now.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var text = result.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].text;  //concatenates the text of all descendant nodes
```

or

```
var text = result.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined," and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined." Every time I try to pass it to a variable to get the text's value, it becomes undefined. When using alert(), it works perfectly. This makes no sense...

Comment: oh you know what, try removing the [0] and use the second option